# drupal on cpanel

Tags: drupal, cpanel

Is drupal good for building an online store?
How do I install drupal on cpanel?  I don't want to use the automatic installation on cpanel, since I heard it is less customizable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal has excellent modules for building an online store.

Use cPanel to setup [FTP](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/FTPAccounts) or [SSH](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_cpanel.htm) access, then you'll be able to upload the Drupal tar ball - detailed instructions for [installing Drupal here](http://drupal.org/node/1011872).

Answer (score 0):

Some modules for creating an online store in Drupal:

- [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart)
- [Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce)

They each have dependencies, that is, modules that are required in order for them to run. They are two different approaches to creating a store in Drupal, so you'd use one or the other. Make sure you read the project descriptions listed to see which fulfil your needs the best.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is indeed known as one of the most robust CMS. It is not as used as WordPress with WooCommerce installed but it is still a pretty solid choice. I personally would recommend PrestaShop

You can easily install Drupal if your hosting provider offers Softaculous in your cPanel as well

Otherwise you need to do the following:

- Download Drupal from their site
- Upload the archive to your cPanel account, in the Directory Root for your domain
- Extract the archive from within your cPanel's File Manager
- Create a MySQL User and Database, assign the User to the Database (done through MySQL Wizard)
- Proceed with the installation by visiting your website

Answer (score 0):

To install Drupal 8 on cPanel not using Softaculous:

1. Use the "MySQL Database Wizard" to create a new database
2. Give the database a name & create a user with all privileges
3. Download the .zip/.gzip file for the latest [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/download) package
4. Upload the file & unpack (Using File Manger in cPanel) to the root folder for the domain name
5. Change the name on the settings.php file in the sites/default folder
6. Run the Drupal 8 installation script from the domain root, entering the DB information

Make sure to keep the Drupal CMS & contributed modules up to date with the latest security versions in production.